# Returning and displaying contents of ArrayList in different class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a project where I will tally a Student's choices and add them to a count array (still working on this part). For now, I'm trying to retrieve the choices that have been sent and added to a Student ArrayList in my Student class.

Student class:

```
public class Students {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Integer> choices = new ArrayList<Integer>();


public Students(){
    name = " ";
}

public Students(String Name){
    name = Name;
}

public void setName(String Name){
    name = Name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void addChoices(int Choices){
    choices.add(Choices);
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getChoices(){
    return choices;
}
```

Here is my main driver class:

```
public class P1Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    ArrayList<Students> students = new ArrayList<Students>();
    String[] choices = new String[100];
    int[] count;
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("Choices.txt"));
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("EitherOr.csv"));

    // Scan the first file.
    int choicesIndex = 0;
    while(scan1.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan1.nextLine();
        choices[choicesIndex] = line;
        choicesIndex++;
    }
    scan1.close();

    // Scan the second file.
    int studentIndex = 0;
    while(scan2.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan2.nextLine();
        String [] splits = line.split(","); 

        students.add(new Students(splits[0]));

        for(int i = 1; i < splits.length; i++){
            students.get(studentIndex).addChoices(Integer.parseInt(splits[i]));
        }
        studentIndex++;
    }
    scan2.close();

    // Instantiate and add to the count array.
    int countIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
        if(students.get(i).getChoices(i) == -1){

        }
    }
```

The last part is where I am now. It's nowhere near done obviously (I'm right in the middle of it) but during my construction of a for loop to get the choices from the students, I'm getting an error that says, **"The method getChoices() in the type Students is not applicable for the arguments (int)."** Can someone explain what this means, where me error is, and possibly how to fix it? Thanks all.

Comment: `getChoices()` does not have any arguments defined, but you try to pass it `i`.

Comment: I see, I was trying to use i to mark the index of the ArrayList. So I should add an index to pass through the parameter? Like:

public ArrayList<Integer> getChoices(int index)? Let me know if I'm still off base!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getChoices(int i)` is not a method you've defined.

```
if(students.get(i).getChoices(i) == -1){

}
```

`getChoices()` returns a list, so you can just use the `get` method on the list:

```
if(students.get(i).getChoices().get(i) == -1){

}
```

Alternatively, make a `getChoice` method:

```
public Integer getChoice(int i){
    return choices.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getChoices()[i] instead of getChoices(i)

Comment: `[]` only works on arrays, not `ArrayList`s; correct usage would be `getChoices().get(i)`.